# How to implement UISearchController in iOS8?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, ios8, uisearchcontroller

I have tried to implement the UISearchController in IOS8 but failed.

The problem is when I have changed the text and the scope button, noting is presented to me.

And it seems that the updateSearchResultsForSearchController function is not even called when I update the search Bar or the scope button.

Here is my code:

```
class SearchTestController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

struct Candy {
    let category : String
    let name : String
}

var searchcontroller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)




func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    filteredcandy = candies.filter() { (candy:Candy) -> Bool in
        let scopetest = ( self.category[self.searchcontroller.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex] == "All" ) || ( candy.category == self.category[self.searchcontroller.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex] )
        //let texttest = candy.name.rangeOfString(self.searchcontroller.searchBar.text)
        //let result = scopetest && (texttest != nil)
        return scopetest
    }
    println(filteredcandy.count)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}


var candies = [Candy]()
var filteredcandy = [Candy]()
var category = ["Chocolate","Hard","Other","All"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Sample Data for candyArray
    self.candies = [Candy(category:"Chocolate", name:"chocolate Bar"),
        Candy(category:"Chocolate", name:"chocolate Chip"),
        Candy(category:"Chocolate", name:"dark chocolate"),
        Candy(category:"Hard", name:"lollipop"),
        Candy(category:"Hard", name:"candy cane"),
        Candy(category:"Hard", name:"jaw breaker"),
        Candy(category:"Other", name:"caramel"),
        Candy(category:"Other", name:"sour chew"),
        Candy(category:"Other", name:"gummi bear")]



    // Reload the table
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchcontroller.searchBar
    searchcontroller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchcontroller.searchBar.showsSearchResultsButton = true
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    searchcontroller.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = category

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searchcontroller.active {
        return self.candies.count
    } else {
        return self.candies.count
    }

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //ask for a reusable cell from the tableview, the tableview will create a new one if it doesn't have any
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell

    var candy : Candy
    // Check to see whether the normal table or search results table is being displayed and set the Candy object from the appropriate array
    if searchcontroller.active {
         candy = filteredcandy[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        candy = candies[indexPath.row]
    }


    // Configure the cell
    cell.textLabel!.text = candy.name
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Did you set the delegate for the search controller?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines to `viewDidLoad()`

```
searchcontroller.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchcontroller.delegate = self
```

Update:

Add the following line in `viewDidLoad()`

```
searchcontroller.searchBar.delegate = self
```

Then update the search results in [`searchBar(_:selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchBarDelegate/searchBar:selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:)

Comment: thanks, that did solve the problem. But I have another problem, I find the result only got updated when I update the search text, but not when I update the scope button, this is inconsistent with the documentation of Apple. Is this a bug ?

Comment: Thanks, Praveen, I know this would work, just think it is kind of awkward and redundant to do it this way, the updateSearchResultsForSearchController() function should work as it was described in the document.

Comment: It probably is a bug, to get it to work call `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` from `selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange` as shown [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2015/02/16/updating-to-the-ios-8-search-controller.html).
I had to resort to the same hack in my app which uses scope bar with `UISearchController`